# Entity Framework Core 2.0 Recreating all DB Tables

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

Every time I run `dotnet ef migrations add <migration_name>` the migration created recreates all the DB tables. When then trying to run the migration I obviously get a message that the table already exists.

What am I missing? I am using the following packages;

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
```

I also have this in the `csproj`;

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
```

Comment: Only run add migrations once
Remove Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design

Comment: Thanks @ErikEJ, how would I then add new properties to a model and add those to the DB table? Is it all manual?

Comment: How and when do you run the migrations?

Comment: I run `dotnet ef database update` but the issue is not in the running. The issue is in the actual generating. When I look at what the `dotnet ef migrations add` generates it wants to recreate already created tables. It does not detect that those tables exist and that it's just a column that I'm adding.

Answer (score 0):

If the database already exists and you want to make changes to your model, you use `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourContextName>`

Comment: Thanks @Trinity. Not sure what you are saying? Where or how do I use `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourContextName>`?

Comment: In your DbInitializer. 
public class YourContextSeedInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<YourContext>

Comment: I don't think EF Core has DB initializers?